# How to integrate gtm for both android and ios combine?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have an android and ios app and I want to use same Google Analytics account as ios in android. I used tracking id of ios in android json file as well as tags in GA account. Anyone please guide me how can I use one GA account in both iOS and Android ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GTM + Firebase implementation. Adding GTM as a control layer before sending data to GA allow you to a lot of things a have control without the need of updating the app.

[iOS Docs](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/)

[Android Docs](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/)

You ll need two different GTM containers but you can send from both of this to the same GA account.

Hope it helps !

Comment: How can I send event from both different gtm containers to same GA account?